# Understanding [[I.class referenced in some Java source

Tags: java, reflection

I'm looking at some Java reflection sourcecode that goes like this:

```
Method fixTransparentPixels = TextureAtlasSprite.class.getDeclaredMethod("fixTransparentPixels", new Class[] { [[I.class });
```

The method being referenced is declared like so:

```
private void fixTransparentPixels(int[][] p_147961_1_) {...}
```

What I do not understand is the `[[I.class` part. Now, I get that the actual `Class[]` array is to determine which form of the declared method you want (what parameter types etc.), but what does `[[I.class` actually mean?

Furthermore, when I try to write this reflection code myself, my IDE gives me syntax errors on the `[[I.class` bit. Can anyone give me any info on this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[I` is the internal name of the class for `int[][]`:
`System.out.println(int[][].class.getName());` outputs `[[I`
or `Class.forName("[[I")` == `int[][].class`.

However, it's illegal to write `[[I.class` in source code. You should write `int[][].class` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

When using `getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)` the `parameterTypes` must be the class of the parameter (obviously). So in this case `fixTransparentPixels` require a `int[][]`, so the parameterTypes will be `int[][].class`.

This will works :

```
TextureAtlasSprite.class.getDeclaredMethod("fixTransparentPixels", int[][].class);
```